# Add regression line to a shap.dependence_plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, loess, shap

Is it possible to add a regression line to the result of `shap.dependence_plot` of the `shap` Python package?

Toy example:

```
import xgboost
import shap

# train XGBoost model
X,y = shap.datasets.adult()
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)

# compute SHAP values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

# The shap dependence plot
shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values, X)
```

would be possible to plot in a simple way a regression line like LOESS?

Comment: https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/plots/dependence_plot.html Check this out. Here they have tried editing the plot with `plt` functions. As `dependence_plot` returns a scatter plot, hence, treating it as a normal plot and then adding a regression line should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
import xgboost
import shap

# train XGBoost model
X,y = shap.datasets.adult()
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)

# compute SHAP values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

import statsmodels.api as sm

idx = np.where(X.columns=="Age")[0][0]
x = X.iloc[:,idx]
y_sv = shap_values[:,idx]
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y_sv, x, frac=.3)

_,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*list(zip(*lowess)), color="red", )

shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values, X, ax=ax)
```

[image]