# SHAP dependence plots (scatter with a regression trend line and Histogram)

Tags: python, matplotlib, shap

I want to draw shap partial dependence plots with regression lines and histograms, similar to the figure from the referenced article below.

[Here is the Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAmA8.png)

**Reference Article **: Kim, S.H., Jeon, E.T., Yu, S., Oh, K., Kim, C.K., Song, T.J., Kim, Y.J., Heo, S.H., Park, K.Y., Kim, J.M. and Park, J.H., 2021. Interpretable machine learning for early neurological deterioration prediction in atrial fibrillation-related stroke. Scientific reports, 11(1), p.20610.

How can I modify the original SHAP dependence plot code below to include the regression line and histogram as shown in the figure above? This code can only give me the scatter plot.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf)

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.dependence_plot("var_1", shap_values[1], X_test, interaction_index=None, color='orange',show=False)
```

Regards
Umer

I tried to add a separate axis. However, it did not work.
`ax = plt.gca()`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try here for your first question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65047292/4317058

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html, and subfigures (google "matplotlib subfigures"). Re the "regression" line (I doubt it is a regression line) you're on your own, at least until you tell us what's the matter..